# Nginx redirects static files to subdir of root

Tags: javascript, css, image, nginx, static

I have an app that runs at `http://192.168.0.2:8080/`. The index.html page is in `/web` folder and it requests static files (eg. css) at `/css`.

I'd like to use `nginx` as reverse proxy and to have `myapp.mydomain.com` to redirect to my app. 
I have the following configuration in my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  myapp.mydomain.com;
        satisfy any;
        location / {
                proxy_pass  http://192.168.0.2:8080/web/;
                index  index.html index.htm;
        }
}
```

but it does not work for `css` files since it looks for them at `/web/css`.
My workaround is to have my `nginx.conf` configured this way (without `/web`):

```
server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  myapp.mydomain.com;
            satisfy any;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass  http://192.168.0.2:8080/;
                    index  index.html index.htm;
            }
    }
```

and request `http://myapp.mydomain.com/web` each time.

But I'd like to be able to request `http://myapp.mydomain.com/` and let `nginx` manage.

I think something similar to that may help but I can't find how:

```
location ~ .(css|img|js)/(.+)$ {
                try_files $uri /$uri /$1/$2;
        }

location / {
                proxy_pass  http://192.168.0.2:8080/web/;
                index  index.html index.htm;
        }
```

Here is my complete file, with auth etc:

```
upstream app { server 192.168.0.2:8080; }
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  myapp.mydomain.com myapp.myOtherDomain.com;
        satisfy any;
        allow 192.168.0.0/24;
        deny all;
        auth_basic "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth/passwords;
        location / { proxy_pass http://app/web/; }
        location /css { proxy_pass http://app; }
        location /img { proxy_pass http://app; }
        location /js { proxy_pass http://app; }
}
```

Any idea how I can fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please expand your question to include the entire `server { ... }` container. Please give an example URL for a css resource that is being mapped to `/web/css`.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Perhaps all you need is `location = / { rewrite ^ /web/; }`

Comment: Where should I put that? I cannot understand, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a working configuration and the *only* problem is that you would like the URL `http://myapp.mydomain.com/` to be mapped to `http://192.168.0.2:8080/web/`.

Your working configuration is:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  myapp.mydomain.com;
  satisfy any;
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://192.168.0.2:8080/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

The simplest solution is to add an exact match for the `/` URI. Such as:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  myapp.mydomain.com;
  satisfy any;
  location = / { rewrite ^ /web/; }
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://192.168.0.2:8080/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks a lot. Very cleaver. While I wanted to rewrite all the static files, you rewrite the web. Thank you very much again.